# Android doesn't terminate ASyncTask thread after onPostExecution

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an instance of ASyncTask in my application which is used to log a user into the application, the problem is that when the ASyncTask as executed the "onPostExecution" function, the ASyncTask thread remains "running" (as shown in the Eclipse Debugger). The onPostExecution only modifies UI components and (in the case of successful login), start a new activity.

How can I terminate the thread?

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407408/asynctask-keeps-waiting/8407518#8407518).

Answer (score 5):

For executing the `AsyncTask`, Android uses a **thread pool** so all `Thread` objects are automatically recycled. So *there is no need to kill manually the thread*.

For this job there are two static fields in `AsyncTask`: `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` and `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, instances of [`Executor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) that are used when you call `asyncTask.execute(Params... params)`.

If you need more control you can use the alternative method `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params)` specifying another `Executor` instance - for example you can use [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) that gives you an [`ExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instance. In this way you can "shutdown" the `ExecutorService`, destroying definitively all threads, calling the method [`executor.shutdown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29).

Comment: These fields SERIAL_EXECUTOR and THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,and method executeOnExecutor() are available only above API 11+.is there any workaround for the api versions less than 11 ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you need the thread terminated? Normally you would allow the system to handle this but in my experience once you use an `AsyncTask` its thread stays around waiting to execute another `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I have different activities which use new AsyncTask objects, so a stack of these threads is created, but most are not used more than once.

Comment: Don't worry about it, the system is acting normally. They existing thread is held in memory to prevent another thread from being created. (In my experience up to 3 per app.) Rest assured that the tasks are finishing but staying around in case they are needed again.

Answer (score 0):

just check the running threads in your application

if your project is in java application:

```
int active = Thread.activeCount();
System.out.println("currently active threads: "+active);
Thread all[] = new Thread[active];
Thread.enumerate(all);
for (int i = 0; i < active; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + all[i]);
}
```

if you r using android project application:

```
String run="";
int active =Thread.activeCount();
System.out.println("currently active threads: " + active);
Thread all[] = new Thread[active];
Thread.enumerate(all);

for (int i = 0; i < active; i++) {
    run+=all[i]+"\n";
}
// declare the EditText in your main thread
edittext.setText(run);
```