# AsyncTask issue

Tags: android

In my app there r 6-9 AsyncTask  they get fired by onlick event ,but after 5 Asynctask other asynctask doesnot run in 2.1 emulator.on DDMS Thread view I can see all 5 AsyncTask are on waiting status hence other asycntask dosent.
Any help would apprecited .Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Majid bhai, why you are use many asyntask

Comment: @AshishDwivedi  For 5 tabs i have 5 list view which gets data from server..so user can move from one tab to another n data get downladed asynchronously..even list hv some btns which contact server ..hence to do all this I have used asynctask rather thread.

Comment: @Majid you should be override onCancelled() method of asynctask in each tab

Answer (score 1):

By default in most versions of Android, only 5 threads are spawned to process AsyncTasks unless the queue is full. This is fine though as hopefully you're not counting on these AsyncTasks to be processed in any sort of order, any of the others will get processed once any of the first 5 are done.

Comment: once task is done asynctask is der in memory in waiting status..even cancelling them didnt work..

Comment: No, the AsyncTask will finish. However, the threads in your threadpool will still be there. See this [answer to another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407408/asynctask-keeps-waiting/8407518#8407518).

Comment: so if all my 5 task r done.. then other asynctask should run but this is not case...they just dont run..

Comment: @Majid Maybe you could post your code so that we can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: When setting the targetSDKVersion to 13 or higher and running on Android 4.0 AsyncTask has only one worker Thread and runs not in parallel. http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to lauch one after another, or do you want all of them to be executed at once, i fear that as i remember that atmost 5 task can run simultaneously, though i the latest api i think this also has changed.

THANKS

Comment: I have 5 tabs each have a asynctask n m not running all simulataneouly it is one by one ..but as count goes above 5 no other asynctask runs

Comment: yes...i think 5 task limitaition takes place here...plus i also think that you are not executing it properly......

Comment: @Majid Maybe your tasks do not finish?