# Android: Clean up AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Over time my app using a lot of AsyncTasks, and I noticed in the debugger that they don't go away and even when they are done they still show up as an active thread. Is there any way after the task is done to tell the garbage collector to kill it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AsyncTask keeps waiting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407408/asynctask-keeps-waiting)

Comment: Make it null after finishing using it, usually in Activity.onDestroy() callback method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Lenik pointed out below that my original answer was not the proper android way to cancel an AsyncTask.

AsyncTask has a complete and elegant system for cancelling. Call the `cancel(true)` method on your task when you're ready to cancel. If you're running an internal loop, use `isCancelled()` to check the status, and exit the loop appropriately if it returns `true`. This has the added benefit of calling your `onCancelled(Object)` method on the UI thread after `cancel(boolean)` is invoked and `doInBackground(Object[])` has finished. Then set the reference to your task to null.

Thanks Lenik! If you post an answer, I'll delete this one so you receive credit.

Comment: is there any reason to use `isInterrupted` instead of existing and well documenter `isCancelled()` and `AsyncTask.cancel()` ?

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! (will revise my answer or if you'd prefer to answer that's fine too.)